Swapping of token to USDT or USDC
I need a review and the best optimized way to implement this contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract LodeProtocolPayment is Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
    ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter;

    address public immutable ETH;
    address public immutable TOKEN;
    address public immutable USDT;

    uint24 public constant FEE_TIER = 3000; // Uniswap pool fee (0.3%)

    event PaymentProcessed(
        address indexed payer,
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 equivalentUSDT,
        string tokenType
    );

    constructor(
        address _swapRouter,
        address _Eth,
        address _token,
        address _usdt
    ) Ownable(msg.sender) {
        swapRouter = ISwapRouter(_swapRouter);
        ETH = _Eth;
        TOKEN = _token;
        USDT = _usdt;
    }

    function payInEth() external payable nonReentrant {
        require(msg.value > 0, "LodePaymentProcessor: No ETH sent");

        uint256 usdtReceived = _swapExactInputSingle(msg.value, ETH);
        _sendToAdmin(USDT, usdtReceived);

        emit PaymentProcessed(msg.sender, msg.value, usdtReceived, "ETH");
    }

    function payInTOKEN(uint256 amount) external nonReentrant {
        require(amount > 0, "LodePaymentProcessor: No TOKEN sent");

        IERC20(TOKEN).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        IERC20(TOKEN).approve(address(swapRouter), amount);

        uint256 usdtReceived = _swapExactInputSingle(amount, TOKEN);
        _sendToAdmin(USDT, usdtReceived);

        emit PaymentProcessed(msg.sender, amount, usdtReceived, "TOKEN");
    }

    function payInUSDT(uint256 amount) external nonReentrant {
        require(amount > 0, "LodePaymentProcessor: No USDT sent");

        IERC20(USDT).transferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), amount);
        emit PaymentProcessed(msg.sender, amount, amount, "USDT");
    }

    function _swapExactInputSingle(
        uint256 amountIn,
        address tokenIn
    ) internal returns (uint256 amountOut) {
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: tokenIn,
                tokenOut: USDT,
                fee: FEE_TIER,
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle{
            value: tokenIn == ETH ? amountIn : 0
        }(params);
    }

    function _sendToAdmin(address token, uint256 amount) internal {
        if (token == ETH) {
            (bool success, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: amount}("");
            require(success, "Transfer to admin failed");
        } else {
            IERC20(token).transfer(owner(), amount);
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}

The logic is to:

Accept payments in ARBETH and ARB.
Convert the received amount in ARB and ARBETH to USDT.
Make payment with USDT.
Emit an event with the equivalent USD amount.
Allow an admin to monitor these payments.
Transfer the payment to admin address immediately.

